# Consistent way to typeset modality symbols

Tags: symbols, typography, math-operators, logic, amssymb

In logic, modalities are often represented by a geometric symbol before a proposition, where the choice of the shape is strongly determined by tradition.

`amsfonts` and `amssymb` provides various symbols such as `\square` and `\lozenge` that looks good right off the bat.

However, searching for more symbols seems to be particularly challenging.
Since modalities are often chained, the visual height and stroke thickness should be roughly the same to fit well.
I did an extensive search through the symbols table, and if I haven't missed anything, none of the circles seem to pass the criterion. Similarly `\triangleleft` and the like don't have the same height.

[image: Reference image showcasing circles, squares and triangles.]

These symbols should either be `\mathord` or treated like the differential `d` (with a thin space before and none after).
Here's an example of a book I happen to have by hand.
[image: Scanned page of a book]
Currently I'm resorting to drawing the symbol using TikZ. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you please show some examples of such symbols and how you want them to look? Also, what class do they belong to and what spacing do you think they should have with respect to other symbols (relation, binary operators, ...)

Comment: Logic is surprisingly poorly supported in LaTeX. As you suggest, even when the symbols are available, you often need to redo the spacing as their meaning is different. I've only every needed the most basic modal operators and most people reading this won't have used any at all, so the code you're using for necessity and possibility, together with the Ti*k*Z code you're using for the others would give you a much better chance of getting help.

Comment: I'd add this request to that of @mickep: If there is a published document, preferably one produced by "traditional methods", that shows such symbols properly in context, showing a scan of a page or two with such usage would be enormously helpful.

Comment: @mickep I'm satisfied with circles but it would be nice if there is some package that deals with more. As I stated the symbols should be of roughly the same visual height and thickness with each other, the amssymb square and lozenge is a good example.

Comment: What's the circle's meaning? (This is a logic question rather than a TeX question.) Please post code people can compile with what you're using/have already. (This is a TeX SE point rather than a logic point.)

Comment: @cfr It may have a special meaning in this context but in temporal logic it's the "next-time operator". Explanation (but different notation) here: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-temporal/#AddNexTimOpe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`logix`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/logix) package. It requires a Unicode engine (lualatex or xelatex). The symbols are available in both math and text mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{logix}

\begin{document}
\FacNec\FacPos\FacNext\FacFutr\FacPast\FacCont\FacNonCont
\end{document}
```

[image]

According to the package, they were designed for use with the Stix fonts, so if the logix fonts don't match the font you're using you could try adding the following to the preamble:

```
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
```

Comment: This completely fits the bill (apart from having to change my font, which I can personally accept)! I'll wait a bit to see if there are better answers.

Answer (score 3):

You already have a good LaTeX answer, using the logix package with its specific font (that indeed seems to cover a lot when it comes to typesetting logic). I think there is a place for a ConTeXt lmtx answer, if not to make more people aware of the possibility to define new math classes for this kind of task, and to set up consistent spacing.

If we run `context` on the file

```
% \showglyphs
% \showmakeup[mathglue]
% \setupbodyfont[pagella]

\registerengineclass [modal] [MOD]

\setnewconstant  \mathmodalcode  \mathclassvalue   modal
\copymathspacing \mathmodalcode  \mathordinarycode


\Umathchardef \modalnecessary \mathmodalcode   0 "25A1
\Umathchardef \modalpossible  \mathmodalcode   0 "25CA
\Umathchardef \modalnext      \mathmodalcode   0 "25CB
\Umathchardef \modalleft      \mathmodalcode   0 "22B2
\Umathchardef \modalright     \mathmodalcode   0 "22B3
\Umathchardef \modalU         \mathbinarycode  0 "1D4B0

\starttext
\startTEXpage[offset=1DK]
Some inline formulas:

\im {\modalnecessary _F(\varphi \rightarrow \psi ) \rightarrow (\modalnecessary _F \varphi \rightarrow \modalnecessary _F \psi)}

\im {\modalnext (\varphi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow (\modalnext  \varphi \rightarrow \modalnext  \psi)}

\im {\modalnext \neg\varphi \leftrightarrow \neg\modalnext \varphi}

\im {\varphi \modalU \psi \rightarrow \modalpossible_F \psi}

\im {\modalleft \psi \rightarrow \neg \modalright \varphi}

Changing the spacing:

\im{A\modalnecessary B \neq A \square B}

\inherited\setmathspacing \mathordinarycode \mathmodalcode \allsplitstyles  \thinmuskip
\inherited\setmathspacing \mathordinarycode \mathmodalcode \allscriptstyles \pettymuskip

\im{A\modalnecessary B \neq A \square B}
\stopTEXpage
\stoptext
```

we get

[image: modal output]

A few comments are in place:

- I'm not into modal logic, so I'm not sure exactly what is wanted.
- The `\startTEXpage` and `\stopTEXpage` are only there to give a small page for this example.

Now to the important parts:

- The `\registerclass` and `\setnewconstant` initiate a new atom class. The `\copymathspacing` makes sure that by default it gets the same interatom spacing as the ordinary class.
- The `\Umathchardef` lines define various math characters, having the new class. Note: I just choose the names a bit randomly. The `\modalU` could of course motivate a new atom class `modalbinary` that inherited the spacing from the binary atom class, with modifications, if needed. (Maybe it shall not have spacing as binary operators at all?)
- The formulas are then just set in inline math mode (`\im`)
- At the bottom, we show how to set up the spacing in case one really wants to set it up. Here we setup the space between the ordinary class our new class, and we do it for `\allsplitstyles` (all non-script styles) and `\allscriptstyles` (all scriptstyles), but one can be more granular.

If one wants to debug and see the spacing a bit better, one can uncomment the first two lines.

[image: With glyphs and spacings marked]

This approach also makes it possible to switch fonts as one wants. It depends on the font if it looks good or not. If we instead uncomment the third line, we get

[image]